# Website returning response 200 in found directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, fuzzing

I am currently building a recursive URL fuzzer and I've found this peculiar problem that I can't find a solution online.

Currently, I've already built the fuzzer where when I find a directory that gives me a response 200 when it has found a working directory. The default, without the recursion function works well.

However, the program starts acting weirdly when I do the recursive function. For example, I have found a working directory http://localhost/website/images, using the program, I've appended a / to the directory to make it become http://localhost/website/images/ ,next, I repeat the function again, appending my wordlist to http://localhost/website/images/ to become for example, http://localhost/website/images/images.

The problem starts here, when the website receives http://localhost/website/images/images, it will return a response code of 200.

Even a directory like http://localhost/website/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/hello/hello/hello returns a response code of 200.

Is this a result of a security mechanism set in by the website?

My codes are as shown below :

```
def recursiveURL(URLtoTake):
   with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      website = URLtoTake +"/" + line
      URL = requests.get(website)
      if URL.status_code == 200: 
         foundsites.append(website)
         print "Found :" + website
         recursiveURL(website)

      else:
         print "Not Found"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. This is very unclear. What does "where when I find a directory that gives me a response 200 when it has found a working directory" mean? What is "the recursive function"? Sharing some actual code would help.

Comment: @Chris edited with my codes. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the website. Plenty of websites will return 404 for a directory that doesn't exist.